# NullReferenceException when passing Arg.Any<int>() as argument using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

I have a customer class which accepts an IDbGateway interface as a constructor parameter. I need to write a unit test CalculateWage_HourlyPayed_ReturnsCorrectWage for the class using NUnit and NSubstitute. My unit test works fine when I pass **anyId**. But I want to pass `Arg.Any<int>()` instead of **anyId**. At the moment my test fails because  `decimal actual = sut.CalculateWage(Arg.Any<int>());` gives `NullReferenceException`. Why is my code working for anyId value pass but not for `Arg.Any<int>()`?

Here are the target members

```
public class Customer
{
    private readonly IDbGateway _gateway;

    public Customer(IDbGateway gateway)
    {
        _gateway = gateway;
    }

    public decimal CalculateWage(int id)
    {
        WorkingStatistics ws = _gateway.GetWorkingStatistics(id);

        decimal wage;

        if (ws.PayHourly)
        {
            wage = ws.WorkingHours * ws.HourSalary;
        }
        else
        {
            wage = ws.MonthSalary;
        }

        return wage;
    }
}

public interface IDbGateway
{
    WorkingStatistics GetWorkingStatistics(int id);
}

public class DbGateway : IDbGateway
{
    public WorkingStatistics GetWorkingStatistics(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class WorkingStatistics
{
    public decimal HourSalary { get; set; }
    public int WorkingHours { get; set; }
    public decimal MonthSalary { get; set; }
    public bool PayHourly { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the test in question

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomerTestsWithNSubstitute
{
    [Test]
    public void CalculateWage_HourlyPayed_ReturnsCorrectWage()
    {
        var gateway = Substitute.For<IDbGateway>();
        var workingStatistics = new Business.Demo.WorkingStatistics()
        { PayHourly = true, HourSalary = 100, WorkingHours = 10 };
        const int anyId = 1;
        //gateway.GetWorkingStatistics(anyId).ReturnsForAnyArgs(workingStatistics);
        gateway.GetWorkingStatistics(Arg.Any<int>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(workingStatistics);

        const decimal expectedWage = 100 * 10;
        var sut = new Customer(gateway);

        //decimal actual = sut.CalculateWage(anyId);
        decimal actual = sut.CalculateWage(Arg.Any<int>());

        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expectedWage).Within(0.1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arg.*` are meant to be used in arranging/stubbing the mocked behavior.

They are not meant to be used as actual parameter values when exercising the test

> Argument matchers should only be used when specifying calls for the purposes of setting return values, checking received calls, or configuring callbacks (for example: with *`Returns`, `Received` or `When`*). Using `Arg.Is` or `Arg.Any` in other situations can cause your tests to behave in unexpected ways.

Reference [How NOT to use argument matchers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/#how_not_to_use_argument_matchers)

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomerTestsWithNSubstitute {
    [Test]
    public void CalculateWage_HourlyPayed_ReturnsCorrectWage() {
        //Arrange
        var gateway = Substitute.For<IDbGateway>();
        var workingStatistics = new Business.Demo.WorkingStatistics()
        { PayHourly = true, HourSalary = 100, WorkingHours = 10 };
        const int anyId = 1;
        
        //Use Arg.* here
        gateway.GetWorkingStatistics(Arg.Any<int>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(workingStatistics);

        const decimal expectedWage = 100 * 10;
        var sut = new Customer(gateway);

        //Act
        decimal actual = sut.CalculateWage(anyId); //<-- Use actual value here

        //Assert    
        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expectedWage).Within(0.1));
    }
}
```

Reference [Argument matchers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/)